# Driving a solenoid with low voltage source

Tags: microcontroller, power-supply, analog, solenoid

I have a 5V solenoid here, but my power source (battery) is only 3.3V . It's a pretty small solenoid, so it doesn't need huge amounts of power, but directly connecting it to the battery terminals wont move it. The battery will be a LiPo, so that shouldn't be limiting the current much.

A microcontroller will be present already in the system, so a boost converter could be implemented, but space is a bit of a premium, so if anyone has any better ideas to up the voltage it would be great to hear them. All that's needed is a pulse of high voltage and current, as the solenoid will be pressing a button (and no, the button cant be bypassed directly). The solenoid works well around 7-8V, so that would be the target.

Comment: Why do you need a microcontroller for a boost converter o_O ?

Comment: Boosting into a capacitor then discharging that through the solenoid is a common solution. How little space do you really have?

Comment: How long does it take for the solenoid to get to the point where the button's pressed, how long does the button need to be pressed, and what's the resistance of the solenoid's winding?  Better yet, can you edit your post to display the solenoid's data sheet or can you post a link to the solenoid's data sheet?

Comment: If you have a microcontroller, you can make a boost converter with just a transistor, cap, diode and inductor, without adding a dedicated chip. It gives you more control over the characteristics of the output, which is important here because we dont really care about the stability of the voltage, we just want a short burst of power.

Comment: Annoyingly, its a chinese knock off of some type, and the datasheet is completely useless/non existent. It literally just lists the dimensions, weight and voltage. The model number is 0408S if anyone wants to look it up. It's a pretty tiny thing, but I will try to measure its inductance and resistance tomorrow, as well as experiment a bit with different voltages/currents.

Comment: can't you get a 3V solenoid? how premium is your space really? whay abouy putting another solenoide behind, or beside the first wired in parallel?

Answer (score 1):

I thought I would work out what is being said (started to being said) in the comments to your question, for the heck of it:

Basically a solenoid needs a magnetic field strong enough to move, so you need a high enough current through it's X windings. To get that current, you usually apply a voltage that induces that current in the given coil.

In the next bit of theorising I will use square-wave signal points to indicate uC outputs.

If you want that voltage without a huge booster built into your system and you can "stand" for the cap to be charging a while, it can be done very small:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5B0B4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The finding of a diode of type "Good One" I leave out of this discussion.

In this, if your solenoid switching is irregular, you might want to make a protection, if you design this too well, eventually it could charge up beyond a break-down voltage somewhere.

You can add another well-configured transistor, maybe two, or a small sot23-5 op-amp configuration and tie it to another uC pin to indicate it should go from regulation mode to burst mode (<0.05 duty cycle).

I have set C1 = 1mF as an absolute limit for myself while designing, because at 16V that is already not going to be very tiny at all.

To find L1, you need to consider uC_pin1's maximum on-time. In this I will assume that it is 100kHz and 50% duty at most, as drawn.

Let's say you have a 2N7002 that handles up to 150mA with the 3.3V (probably easy enough to find, because averaged over time it'll still only dissipate a maximum of about 130mW then)

To find L1, you can calculate the actual curve, that the best to do, but I am not going to, because if you know about those integrals, you already know how to do it and if you don't know about them, this is a much too small box to go into how those work. In stead, I am going to blatantly (and wrongly) assume the voltage is constant at about 2/3 of the actual input voltage. Then it becomes simply: `I(max) = ( (2/3) * V1 * t ) / L` where V1 is the 3.3V input and t is the time in seconds M1 is turned on.

Remember: You need to calculate I(max) at the maximum input voltage. Since my assumption is not very accurate, I would take 4.5V for a LiIon battery, just to be on the safe side.

The equation above can be re-written as:

`L = ( (2/3) * V1 * t) / I )` which is: `L = ( (2/3) * 3.3V * 10us ) / 150mA =~ 146uH`

Of course, I made a risky assumption on, let's say gut-feeling, not knowing the ESR of the inductor you will choose, so I would say, for your first experiment round up very well: Start with 220uH. Unless you use a beefier MOST.

220uH with 150mA saturation may not be very large, but it itn't tiny either, so you might want to see if you can "up" it to 1MHz, or if you can allow a lower on-time and slower charging. That's down to your requirements.

Now, from fiddly complex maths and stuff I could get a very accurate representation of that current and of how much the voltage on the cap will increase each cycle, but in the real world ESRs and such will bug you anyway, so I'm just going to estimate the second part too.

Again, if you know the equations, you are welcome to them, but I am a bit pressed for time and the most likely readers will not follow them easily through this medium. (Not saying anyone is stupid, just that there's digitally better equipped media or people for that ;-) I'd be spending a lot of time drawing and photographing where I am now )

If M2 is turned off and leakage is small, and the ESRs are average, I would expect the capacitor to rise with 4V in about 550 cycles of M1 at 100kHz at the maximum on-time of 50% with a decent cap of 1mF. But, as I said, the maths I used is shoddy and partly based on gut-feelings and they do sometimes turn out to be off by a factor of two to five. But it's a starting estimate for an experiment.

If that is too slow, you can decrease C1, but the required minimum size of C1 is dictated by the amount of energy the solenoid needs (which I do not know at this time) and all the ESRs in the C1-Solenoid-M2 path. So you could experiment with that value and when it doesn't switch on from the cap charged at 8V or 10V any more, double that value for safety.

---

An alternative you could try is without M2 and without the Capacitor and a small diode substitution:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnOX42.png)</sup>

I didn't look up the IRF530, but I believe it's a bit over-kill. The 9V zener can be various voltages, it depends a bit on the Solenoid to L1 ratio and whether this actually works depends on a few more details, but it is a fun experiment that might work or fail miserably.

In the place of the Zener you can also put other components with an even sharper break-down, such as diac-types, several kinds of TVS or even a gas-discharge tube (mind the MOST breakdown though).

If you shortly pulse M1, long enough to have L1 build up a decent amount of current (which depends on the value of L1 you end up needing, which depends on the Solenoid) it will build up that current, then if you release it, the current can't go anywhere until the zener breaks down. This creates a special case, where there *COULD* be enough "motivation" in the resulting signal on the solenoid to convince it to move. For one-off some experimentation required, for production some parametric testing with a broader range of values.

Also be aware that a zener for currents that are high will get hot, in which case a better device with a more awesome curve, as mentioned above, would be a better choice all around.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, but this is indeed a boost converter. I had looked at this, and while it would work I was hoping that there might be a simpler way, considering that I don't need a steady voltage source, just really a short burst of power. Removing the capacitor might work though, which is good because they can be pretty bulky.

Comment: @BWalker it depends a lot on the solenoid specifics what will work and how well, but you will need to boost one way or another, making 9V out of 4V is boosting, one way or another. In the first scheme it might work well enough with only 10uF, I can't say without solenoid datasheets and some real world tests of my own. The first set-up with maths does use tiny sot23 transistors though, so only the cap may get very large.

Answer (score -1):

Use a DC-DC converter module. There's plant of them available. 
Here's an exmple:
http://www.dx.com/p/dc-3-34v-to-dc-4-35v-adjustable-boost-converter-charger-module-149681#.VXmwAPlVhBc

Comment: I think the current considerations should be taken here, as solenoids are typically driven by short high-current pulses.

Comment: This module can handle a constant 2.5A

Comment: @Alex Not when making 8V from 3V. Probably when making 3V from 8V that'll be fine, but the transistor built into the integrated device on that board has an "Absolute Maximum" rating at 40deg C ambient on a board of size X or Y. Very likely to be the 3A input current they spec with cheap units. 3V, 3A = 9W. With 80% efficiency that leaves less than 1A out at 8V. Might be enough, but it's not 2.5A. And they don't have a large enough board to achieve the spec at all.

Comment: You're right. The heatsink for the LM2596 is just a copper on the other side of their board. 1A is still plenty for a small solenoid that will just "press a button".